# Do we need to build application again while moving it from 32bit machine to 64 bit machine?

Tags: .net, assemblies

Consider an application is built on 32 bit machine. Now I want to move application on 64 bit machine. Do I need to rebuild application once again on 64 bit machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to.

There is both a 32 bit and 64 bit .net framework, and both run on 64 bit windows. That is because 64 bit windows can run 32 bit(x86) by "emulating" a 32 bit OS.

Your assembly is labeled at build time as either 32 bit, 64 bit, or "Any CPU". Any CPU builds will run in the 64 bit framework on 64 bit windows, and 32bit on 32 bit windows.

The least amount of testing is required if you label your builds as 32 bit.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Win x64 fully supports x86 builds.

If your assemblies are built for AnyCPU you should test for both 32bit and 64bit processes.

Answer (score 0):

Until you've tested on 64bit, I'd recommend releasing in explicit 32bit only. We got bit by a 3rd party component that failed on 64bit systems.

It certainly isn't always necessary of course; but a customer's site is a terrible place to do a first test.